# Finding out the common rows present in two collections in MongoDB based on some columns

Tags: mongodb

I've got two nested collections like collection1 and collection2:

Collection1 is like:

```
_id : { name : xyz,
      Rollnumber : 123}
Stats : [ { subject : Maths,
        Examdate : 2020-08-24 },
        { Subject : English,
        Examdate : 2020-08-23 } ]
```

Collection2 is having same structure but few extra rows

I've to delete the rows from collection2 which are present in collection1 based on three columns name, `rollnumber` and `examdate`, if any of the `examdate` is "2020-08-24".

I tried to find the common rows in both the tables using:

```
db.collection1.find()
foreach(function(mydoc){
var name = mydoc._id.name;
var rollnumber = mydoc._id.rollnumber;
Var examdate = ISODate("2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z");

db.collection2.aggregate([
{
 $match : { "$and":[
        {"_id.name" : name},
        {"_id.rollnumber" : rollnumber},
        {"Stats.Updated" : examdate} ] }}]).forEach(printjson); });
```

The query runs fine but doesn't returns any output. Any reason why

Comment: can you post a sample document from collection?

Comment: The document is given in the question itself it contains of _id and stats , within stats there are multiple subject and Examdate for every student .

Comment: In the sample document it is `_id.Rollnumber` but in the query `_id.rollnumber`, perhaps just a typo?

Comment: I tried with the capital's too , the first two fields(name/rollnumber) are working fine the problem is matching examdate as there are multiple examdate's within a single document , how to pick a document if any of the examdate matches my condition

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for. From question it is not quite clear that your `Examdate` contains `time` component or not. I am assuming that it only has `date` component. Based on that your document should look something like below.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "name": "xyz",
      "Rollnumber": 123
    },
    "Stats": [
      {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "Examdate": {
          "$date": "2020-08-23T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "Subject": "English",
        "Examdate": {
          "$date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Notice this `"$date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z"` , time component is absent. If this is the case with your documents than the solution should work. If you have time component in `Examdate` field then let me know in comments.

**Query to get document :-**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id.name": "xyz",
      "_id.Rollnumber": 123,
      "Stats.Examdate": ISODate("2020-08-24")
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YXq0Tgyw03S)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply yes it does have the timestamp field too and they are different for every document.

Comment: Do you need all fields of matching document OR `_id.name` and `_id.Rollnumber` would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I am keeping the previous answer as it is. It would help people getting the context.

This is from the question.

```
db.collection1.find()
foreach(function(mydoc){
var name = mydoc._id.name;
var rollnumber = mydoc._id.rollnumber;
//instead of this iterate mydoc.Stats to find max date.
//Var examdate = ISODate("2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z");
mydoc.Stats.forEach(function(dateDocs){
 //code to find max date
})

db.collection2.aggregate([
{
 $match : { "$and":[
        {"_id.name" : name},
        {"_id.rollnumber" : rollnumber},
        {"Stats.Updated" : examdate} ] }}]).forEach(printjson); });
```

Here is the updated query for dates with time component.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id.name": "xyz",
      "_id.Rollnumber": 123
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Stats"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "Stats.UpdatedString": {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$Stats.Updated"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "name": "$_id.name",
        "Rollnumber": "$_id.Rollnumber"
      },
      "Stats": {
        "$addToSet": "$Stats"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Stats.UpdatedString": "2020-08-24"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Stats.UpdatedString": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iLfvbjxBT7p)

Comment: Hi i tried it , but it didn't worked as expected , plus I've to take the values of name ,rollnumber and examdate from collection 1 and search it in collection 2. If name , rollnumber and examdate (max (date+timestamp)) to be precise) of a document in collection1 matches the same in collection 2 , i want those documents so i could remove them .

Comment: As i can see in question, you are already getting name and rollnumber using forEach loop from collection1. Similarly you can find max examdate also inside that forEach loop. Then you can put those values in the above query.

Comment: _id : { name : xyz,
      Rollnumber : 123}
Stats : [ { subject : Maths,
        Examdate : 2020-08-24(timestamp)},
        { Subject : English,
        Examdate : 2020-08-23(timestamp) } ] . I'm facing difficulty in extracting the max date(timestamp) as it's nested , anyway to extract it  and save it in a variable for my cursor